# Infinite Product over Real Intervals

Tags: real-numbers, infinite-product

Is this a valid mathematical expression?
$$\prod_{n\in[a,b]} n$$
I would think that for $n\in[0,b]$, the product equals $0$, and for $n\in[-a,-b]$, it diverges. Is it possible that such a product would converge to an interesting value for something like $n\in[1/\pi,\pi]$, or is the whole idea nonsense? Has anyone developed a rigorous theory concerning this?

Comment: Pretending that $\Pi$ was defined on an uncountable domain... If $a=b$ the product would be defined. If $a,b>1$ then the product would be positive infinity. If $0<a,b \leq 1$ the product would be asymptotic to 0. If $a=1/b$ and $b>1$ you could make an argument the product would be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Products, like sums, are done over discrete sets to avoid problems with adding uncountably many things (there is no way to make such a theory make sense for real numbers: a sum of uncountably many nonzero reals *always* diverges.

There is, however, a construction analogous to the integral, but with products: it's unsurprisingly called the [product integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral); depending on how you define it, it comes out equal to either
$$ \exp{\left(\int_a^b \log{f(x)} \, dx \right)} $$
or
$$ \exp{\left(\int_a^b f(x) \, dx \right)}; $$
the latter, of course, is used in finding integrating factors.

Comment: What if the domain is countably infinite (like rationals)?

Comment: Let $a_n$ be an enumeration of the rationals, and write $f(a_n)=g(n)$. Then, assuming absolute convergence, $\sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} f(q) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f(a_n) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} g(n) $ is just a normal sum (and likewise with products). If you don't have absolute convergence, I suspect you're stuck.

Comment: Makes sense. But seems counter intuitive to me, since reals can be approximated arbitrarily closely by rationals. Oh well, so much for that intuition.